# clap default value - how to use it

Tags: rust, clap

Playing with Rusts clap crate for the first time.
And I wonder how to use the default value of a command line option, when the option was not
specified at the command line.

Given I specified a `default_value` in the yaml file (see snippet below), I expected
the `matches.value_of("VERBOSE")` to return the default value if there is no other value
given in the command line.

Instead, I get:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/main.rs:18:6

I was googling for a while but it seems, no one really gives a canonical example of how it
is supposed to work.

```yaml
...
args:
  - config:
      short: c
      long: config
      value_name: CONFIG
      help: Specifies the config file to use.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: ""
  - verbose:
      short: v
      long: verbose
      value_name: VERBOSE
      help: Sets verbosity. 0 = silent, > 0 = verbose.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: "1"
```

Here, my feeble attempt... compiling but not working (panics if empty command line is used).

```rust
// ...
    let yaml = load_yaml!("cli.yml");
    let matches = App::from_yaml(yaml).get_matches();
    let verbosity =
    matches.value_of("VERBOSE")
    .and_then(|s| s.parse::<u8>().ok())
    .unwrap();
```

As this obviously does not use the default values, my simple question is: How do I do it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you either have a small misconception about what [`value_name`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.3/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.value_name) (which is used only for the CLI help option) is, or you missed, that the argument names are case sensitive.

You have two options to make this work as expected:

1. Use the lowercase argument name as specified in the YAML (change .rs):

YAML:

```yaml
...
args:
  - config:
      short: c
      long: config
      value_name: CONFIG
      help: Specifies the config file to use.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: "1"
  - verbose:
      short: v
      long: verbose
      value_name: VERBOSE
      help: Sets verbosity. 0 = silent, > 0 = verbose.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: "1"
```

Rust:

```rust
use clap::{load_yaml, App};

fn main() {
    let yaml = load_yaml!("cli.yml");
    let matches = App::from_yaml(yaml).get_matches();
    let verbosity =
    matches.value_of("verbose")
    .and_then(|s| s.parse::<u8>().ok())
    .unwrap();
    println!("{}", verbosity);
}
```

2. Use the uppercase name as specified in the Code (change .yaml):
   YAML:

```yaml
...
args:
  - config:
      short: c
      long: config
      value_name: CONFIG
      help: Specifies the config file to use.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: "1"
  - VERBOSE:
      short: v
      long: verbose
      value_name: VERBOSE
      help: Sets verbosity. 0 = silent, > 0 = verbose.
      takes_value: true
      default_value: "1"
```

Rust

```rust
use clap::{load_yaml, App};

fn main() {
    let yaml = load_yaml!("cli.yml");
    let matches = App::from_yaml(yaml).get_matches();
    let verbosity =
    matches.value_of("VERBOSE")
    .and_then(|s| s.parse::<u8>().ok())
    .unwrap();
    println!("{}", verbosity);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, since there is short and long, I assumed value_name is used as a key for the lookup. Oh well. Documentation is rather sparse and I was fixated on my other theory - the default value not working. Thanks!